# What is the rule for converting Fancybox 2 options to HTML5 data attributes?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

Does the option get used as is except lower case or are hyphens added between words? In other words, which is correct for the option **maxWidth**?

```
data-fancybox-maxwidth
```

or

```
data-fancybox-max-width
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of those will work since special `data-fancybox` attributes are restricted to :

- `href`
- `type`
- `group`
- `title`
- `start`

However, you could set your own `data` attributes for an specific API option like :

```
<a rel="gallery" class="fancybox" data-maxwidth="80%"  href="01.jpg"></a>
```

... and set them using jQuery `.extend()` within the `afterLoad` callback like :

```
afterLoad: function(){
    $.extend(this,{
        maxWidth: this.element.data("maxwidth")
    })
}
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/p2ztwvn6/)**

**Notice** that `fitToView` was set to `false` and only the first element has the `data-maxwidth` attribute so it will be the only one in the gallery with `width` constrains.

Comment: Just so you know, this particular case did not involve media. I was trying to display HTML and depending on the use the width could vary. That's why I wanted to send the width in the URL and not as Fancybox options. Thus your proposed extension is probably viable, but I'll continue to use Shadowbox for these cases.

Comment: @WillFastie : you still can use the solution above for any type of content, including media, html, iframe, etc. see http://jsfiddle.net/ugagkbg8/1/ (notice I included `data-fancybox-type` so fancybox will know what type of content to handle)